# Selecting correct font weight variant (Linux)

Tags: fonts, linux

Here's a minimal example that does something on Linux (Ubuntu 16.04) that doesn't seem right to me:

`M-: (set-frame-font "Ubuntu")`
`M-x describe-font <RET>`

The first couple of lines that Emacs 25.1 (-Q) reports are:

```
name (opened by): -DAMA-Ubuntu-normal-normal-normal-*-16-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1
  full name: Ubuntu:pixelsize=16:foundry=DAMA:weight=normal:slant=normal:width=normal:scalable=true
  file name: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ubuntu-font-family/Ubuntu-M.ttf
```

It's the bottom line of this that's wrong (Ubuntu-M.ttf) - Emacs is selecting the "Medium" font weight variant, instead of the "Regular". Like many fonts, the [Ubuntu font has weight variants](http://font.ubuntu.com/) beyond the well-known "Regular" and "Bold". Such additional weights can include "Light", "Book", "Demi-Bold", "Black", "Medium".

I would like to use the Ubuntu Regular font for `variable-pitch-mode`, but the Medium weight isn't suitable. I've tried [various different Emacs ways of specifying a font](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Fonts.html), including `"Ubuntu"`, `"Ubuntu-11:weight=Regular"`, `"-DAMA-Ubuntu-normal-normal-normal-*-15-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1"`.

All of these display text in emacs in the wrong, medium weight. Some apps allow selecting font weight by numbers (e.g. 200=Bold), but not, I believe, Emacs. Still, the system's font selection appears to be correct, and I don't understand why Emacs isn't using this

```
alex@Lucifer:~$ fc-match "Ubuntu"
Ubuntu-R.ttf: "Ubuntu" "Regular"
alex@Lucifer:~$ fc-list "Ubuntu" file family style weight
[correct output]
```

Can anyone confirm that this problem exists on Linux (it works fine on my Windows machine)? And, even better, can anyone point me to how to get Emacs to pick the correct weight of font?

Comment: Have you tried to set it like this "Ubuntu-11:weight=book"? That helped me with Roboto Mono.

Comment: From the code in Emacs' font.c that looks more promising. It looks like Emacs turns the weight names into a number, but treats "regular", "medium" etc. all as 100, which is nearest the Ubuntu font's "medium" weight. "book" should be 75, but sadly this still ends up rendering in Medium.

Comment: And I found out that even adjusting the font size with `text-scale-adjust` will break my workaround. Hope someone more knowledgeable than me can answer this question.

Comment: For some fonts (and, sadly, for others not) it is possible to denote the internal font file name; eg. to use SourceCodePro-regular.ttf I can use `:font "xft:SourceCodePro Regular:size=8"`.  Maybe this works for your font, too.

Answer (score 1):

Not being able to distinguish between "medium" and "regular" weights of fonts on Linux was [reported as a bug](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=32210) on Emacs (not by me, although the discussion references this issue). On 21.10.2021 [a fix was committed to Emacs](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/commit/src/font.c?id=65fd3ca84f75aee0dfebb87fa793dae57c1caf35) git tree (again, not by me, open source ♥).

So the solutions are:

1. Use the latest release of Emacs (version >= 28), or
2. Hide the "medium" weight of the font, either by not installing it or renaming the file extension. This means, of course, that the medium weight will not be available to any application.